# Efficient way of knowing large factors of $\phi(n)$ given small prime factors and $n$

Tags: cryptanalysis, factoring, hardness-assumptions

Knowing large prime factor$(r > n^{1/4})$ of $\phi(n)$ can easily factorize n and hence learn $\phi(n)$.

If we have knowledge on all small prime factors $(2< r_i  << n^{1/4})$ of $\phi(n)$ then, is there any efficient way to factorize $n$ and  $\phi(n)$?

**Note**: $n$ is an RSA number

Comment: What is pi(n)? Normally $\pi(n)$ denotes the number of primes $\le n.$ Do you mean $\varphi(n)?$ Since a RSA number $n$ is often written as $n=pq,$ it would be less confusing if you use another symbol for your factor.

Comment: In general, no; if $p, q$ are both safe-primes, then the product all the small prime factors of $\phi(n) $ is $4$; that knowledge doesn't help very much...